# google chrome AddressBookUrlForwarder pop up when url link clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have the user click on the icon. If the user is on a desktop they will get redirected to the webpage lets use facebook as an example. If the user clicks the icon when in mobile they will be directed to the facebook app but if they do not have it they will go to the webpage via there browser.

The mobile view is fine but on the desktop when the link is clicked this keeps popping up(in chrome).if i use a href tag it doesnt pop up. From a user experience perspective this is annoying. Is there a way to fix this.?

[image]

javascript code im using to direct them to webpage via browser or open app if they have it

```
function goToURL() {
  setTimeout(function () { window.location = "https://www.facebook.com/page/"; }, 8000);
    window.location = "fb://profile/page";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to get rid of the problem. I just took away the

```
 window.location = "fb://profile/page";
```

On the same page I have instagram and soundcloud. For these two i just put in the url for the page and on mobile they open in the app instead on the mobile web browser. For facebook however it does not have this feature(idk why?) it opens up safari and goes to the mobile facebook website. A work around i found was to use a deep link such as URLgenius and it worked. If anyone has ran into this issue i hope it helps you out.